# Backbone change event triggering before response even with wait: true

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm saving a model using Backbone and setting `wait: true`, but one of my listeners is picking up a `change` event on the model before I even get a `success` response from the server. This is causing the rest of my application to render out of date data.

Does anyone have any advice as to why a `change` event would be fired if a. no changes are actually being made to my model (I'm saving it with the same data) and b. `wait` is set to true and the server hasn't even sent a response yet?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. Could be anything from misspelling `wait` or passing the wrong number of arguments to `save()` to accidentally using an ancient version of Backbone. Could even be a totally different field being set from somewhere else in the application. It's extremely hard to even guess without seeing how this happens.

Comment: @ivarni I know, it's production/corporate code so I can't show it, but I was wondering if I could get any advice as to why `change` would fire, or if it is supposed to fire before the `success` response anyways. The function is correct and watching the network traffic everything goes out correctly but I'm picking up a `change` event way before any response.

Comment: "[O]ne of my listeners" sort of implies that there are other listeners that aren't seeing the event. If that's the case, what's different with the misbehaving code? Also, have you looked at the backbone source code? It's well documented and pretty easy to follow.

Comment: @StephenThomas sorry for the vagueness. Regarding the listeners, there is actually only one on the model's view that watches that specific model.
I've spent a bit of time today going through Backbone's docs and source code, and it is actually really nice to go through. One thing that confused me however was http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save where it states `Calling save with new attributes will cause a "change" event immediately` and further down `Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server`. Does this mean passing `wait: true` should halt the `change` event?

Comment: Yes, passing `{ wait: true }` should delay it. We're using it in the application I am currently working with and it works on v1.1.2 at least. The wait was introduced around 0.9 somewhere so if you're on an older version it won't work.